# How do I set the value of an ant DatePicker in React (using react-moment)?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I need to convert this:

`{object.startDate !== null ? <Moment format="MM/DD/YYYY" date={object.startDate}/> : "-----------"}`

into something like this:

`<DatePicker value={Moment format="MM/DD/YYYY" date={object.startDate}} />`

How do I correctly do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing moment (as stated by Sheldon), this is how it tweaked it to make it work:

`<DatePicker value={moment(object.startDate, 'MM/DD/YYYY')} />`

Answer (score 1):

To use `react-moment` it is a must to have `moment` installed.

From the docs:

> "Use npm to install react-moment along with its peer dependency, moment"
> https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-moment

```
import moment from 'moment'
...
<DatePicker value={moment(object.startDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY')} />
...
```

Comment: You're absolutely right about moment being a peer dependency; however, I have to slightly change your answer to make it work (Please see my answer).